# Prevent hibernate/jpa to create proxies

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

With my team, we would like to prevent hibernate from creating proxies. We don't want to use eager fetching type (lazy for all relations) but we want that hibernate returns only attributes fetch with the hql/jpql query. (null for others attributes)

Why ?

Because for performance issue we prefer avoid all "hiding sql request" on "get" and force the developer to write the good jpql/hql query.

is it a good choice ?
Do you know a way to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928411/enable-no-proxy-behaviour-for-all-fetchtype-lazy-non-collections-by-default-in-h

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you want: just don't map the properties with @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @ManyToMany if you don't want the queries to be executed silently. Execute the jpql and set the property marked @Transient "by hand" (e.g. via a DAO)...