# JPA/Hibernate LEFT JOIN FETCH Lazy Exception because joined Entity is Null

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, entity

I have the folowing JPA query:

```
SELECT emp FROM Employee emp LEFT JOIN FETCH emp.supervisor WHERE emp.supervisor_id = :id_number
```

Employee data is structured as follows:

```
employee_ id, first_name, last_name, supervisor_id
           1,       jeff,     jones,             2
           2,        bob,     smith,             3
 etc...
```

where supervisor id is recursive to id of the same table.   The problem is ocassionally I'll get

```
 org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

on the following EL call

```
#{employee.supervisor.last_name}
```

because the data I am using, which is read-only, will have anomalies such as the employee has a supervisor_id on their record, but that employee_id has yet to have been inserted into the system or has been filtered out of the Oracle View that I am allowed to attached my Employee Entity to.

```
employee_ id, first_name, last_name, supervisor_id
           4,       jane,     dean,          9999
where employee_id 9999 doesn't exist in my read-only data feed
```

what I really want is to still grab the Employee Entity but just populate a Null or Empty Supervisor.

Originally I had annotated my Employee Entity with `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` on the supervisor field but that caused the Entity Manager to generate a ton of SQL call degregating the applications performance.  [JPA/Hibernate Query Slow with too many queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546577/jpa-hibernate-query-slow-with-too-many-queries)

```
@Entity
Employee

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//Removed  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "supervisor_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Employee supervisor;
```

Am I missing some constructor on my Employee entity which will populate an empty Supervisor or is there some modification to my query which will perform the `IGNORE` as the annotation did, without a ton of individual SQL calls?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is disable proxy for lazy relationship using proprietary annotation:

```
@org.​hibernate.​annotations.LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
```

After that, lazy left join fetch starts to use null for no occurrence of join instead of a lazy proxy.

There is a HACK to disable it to all *ToOne Lazy fields:

[Enable no-proxy behaviour for all FetchType.LAZY non-collections by default in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928411/enable-no-proxy-behaviour-for-all-fetchtype-lazy-non-collections-by-default-in-h)